# Armature Deform Bone Axis

Tags: bones

Like sorry for the weird title, but I really don't know how to explain what I want to do with few words. So the thing is. I got a sphere and 3 rings around it; I want to make the rings and the sphere rotate constantly on the same axis, I want to specifically do it with armature deform cause is better for the kind of import I want to do later. So I just created one bone for each part, root for the whole ball and one for each ring and assinged the weigth manually to each part, the thing is, the bones that control the ring rotation are 3 and to rotate them in the same axis the bones need to stay in the same point as far as I know; there is a way of not doing it like that? Cause having the 4 bones exactly at the same place is kinda meshy to operate with.

[image]

I want the bones at the top to ratate the rings as if they were in the position of the ROOT one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the rings have to rotate on Z axis only, bones could also remain where they are, but if the rotation has to be on different axis the head of the bones has to be on the pivot point of the desired rotation (as your root's head and 3D cursor).

So the best solution is to give to the bones a custom shape and translate the shape instead of the bone, so to easily manipulate them without moving their head location.

Any mesh with any shape can be a custom shape, in my example 4 bones with same loc rot and scale, but with 4 different custom shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you have multiple bones on top of each other, there are a couple of ways to help with selection.

- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> over the bones, will give you a menu to select the one that you want.

[image]

- You can change the *Display As* option in the *Viewport Display* for the Armature to *B-Bone*. Then you can adjust the width of the bones, to make some wider than others, and easier to click on.

The keystroke to do this changed in Blender 4.0, so:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in versions before 4.0
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in 4.0 and above

[image]

The width change is just a viewport thing. It won't change how the bones behave at all.